# Using Android UI Automator Viewer to dump all elements on a scrollable view?

Tags: android, scroll, screenshot, dump, android-uiautomator

I'm trying to use Android SDK's UI Automator Viewer to take screenshot and dump UI elements of a scrollable view app, unfortunately it can only dump elements on visible screen. I have to manually scroll up or down the view to take other screenshots because the scrollable view is quite long. It results in duplicate elements (elements with same text, resource-id, class) when I combine all elements set into one.

Is there any way to dump ALL elements on a scrollable view at once?

Comment: What framework you are using?